# Get all users email from a group using Active Directory c#

Tags: c#

I need all email address of a particular group. Please help me

```
string filter1 = string.Format("(&(objectClass=group)(cn={0}))", "groupname");
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        searcher.Filter = filter1;
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
        SearchResult res = searcher.FindOne();
        ArrayList userNames = new ArrayList();
        if (res != null)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <res.Properties["member"].Count; counter++)
            {
                string user = (string)res.Properties["member"][counter];
                userNames.Add(user);
            }
        }
```

I am getting uesr name and other details but not get email. Please tell me the way to find email address of each user directly.

Comment: [**What have you tried yourself?**](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `PrincipalContext`  class

```
var username = "username";
var domain = "domain";
var emailAddresses = new List<string>();

var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
var userPrincipal  = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, username);
// Add the "mail" entry
emailAddresses.Add(userPrincipal.EmailAddress);
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb344891(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am using .net version 2.0. I will edit my question for more clearity

Comment: I'am happy to help you, PrincipalContext exists on 2.0 , sample : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38344/Using-System-DirectoryServices-AccountManagement

Comment: I tried your example but PrincipalContext is not recognized by .net. I don't get any option for adding any namespace.

Comment: add assemly before to add namespace

Comment: I had already added the system.DirectoryServices assembly but .net 2.0 doesn't have Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
namespace